# Having Trouble setting up in memory db for unit tests in play 2.4 an Slick 3

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, specs2

I am trying to set up an in Memory h2 db, and then create the necessary tables using Slicks features, for use in my play specs2 tests.  I have created an abstract class that overrides WithApplication and then overrides the around method but I get an error when the createTables function tries to run pre tests.  I suspect that I am not passing in the database connection / config correctly but the error I am getting is not very helpful.  I am creating the db by wrapping plays Databases.withInMemory function

Here is my db helper object

```
package testHelpers

import models.VisitorImages._
import models.VisitorRegistrations._
import models.VisitorSignatures._
import models.VisitorStatuses._
import models.Visitors._
import org.specs2.execute.{Result, AsResult}
import play.api.test.WithApplication
import play.api.{Logger, Application, Play}
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import play.api.db.{Databases, Database}
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.profile.{BasicProfile, RelationalProfile}

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object TestDatabase {
  class testDbProvider extends DatabaseConfigProvider {
    def get[P <: BasicProfile]: DatabaseConfig[P] = {
      DatabaseConfigProvider.get("default")(Play.current)
    }
  }

  def startTestDb[T](block: Database => T) = {
    Databases.withInMemory(
      name = "testDB",
      urlOptions = Map(
        "MODE" -> "MSSQLServer"
      ),
      config = Map(
        "logStatements" -> true
      )
    )(block)
  }

  abstract class WithTestDb extends WithApplication((TestApplication.application)) {
    val profile = slick.driver.H2Driver
    import profile.api._

    override def around[T: AsResult](t: => T): Result = super.around {
      setupData()
      t
    }

    val allTables = (VisitorSignatures.schema ++ VisitorImages.schema ++ Visitors.schema ++ VisitorStatuses.schema ++ VisitorRegistrations.schema
    ).create

    /** Create all tables in database */
    def createTables = {
      Logger.info(s"yadda yadda yadda")
      val db = new testDbProvider().get.db
      Await.result(db.run(Visitors.schema.create), Duration.Inf)
      Logger.info(s"variable user is blah blah")
    }

    /** Delete all tables in database */
    def drop = {
//      allTables.drop
    }

    def setupData() {
      // setup data
      createTables
    }
  }

}
```

Here is how I am trying to use it

```
package unit.models

import models.VisitorRegistrations._
import play.api.{Play, db}
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import play.api.test.{WithApplication, PlaySpecification}
import play.db.NamedDatabase
import providers.VisitorRegistrationProvider
import repositories.VisitorRegistrationRepository
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.lifted.TableQuery
import testHelpers.TestDatabase.WithTestDb
import testHelpers.{Inject, TestApplication, TestDatabase}

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

class VisitorRegistrationsSpec extends PlaySpecification with Inject {
  val vrp = inject[VisitorRegistrationProvider]
  val db = vrp.dbConfig.db

  import vrp.dbConfig.driver.api._

  TestDatabase.startTestDb { database =>
    "VisitorResgistrations" should {
      "save a vr" in new WithTestDb {

        val res = Await.result(db.run(VisitorRegistrations.result), Duration.Inf)

        res must equalTo(1)
      }
    }

  }
}
```

And here is the error I get

```
[info] VisitorResgistrations should
[error]   ! save a vr
[error]    null (Database.scala:61)
[error] testHelpers.TestDatabase$WithTestDb.createTables(Database.scala:61)
[error] testHelpers.TestDatabase$WithTestDb.setupData(Database.scala:72)
[error] testHelpers.TestDatabase$WithTestDb$$anonfun$around$1.apply(Database.scala:50)
[error] play.api.test.WithApplication$$anonfun$around$2.apply(Specs.scala:39)
[error] play.api.test.WithApplication$$anonfun$around$2.apply(Specs.scala:39)
[error] play.api.test.PlayRunners$class.running(Helpers.scala:42)
[error] play.api.test.Helpers$.running(Helpers.scala:363)
[error] play.api.test.WithApplication.around(Specs.scala:39)
[error] testHelpers.TestDatabase$WithTestDb.around(Database.scala:49)
[error] play.api.test.WithApplication.delayedInit(Specs.scala:36)
[error] testHelpers.TestDatabase$WithTestDb.<init>(Database.scala:45)
[error] unit.models.VisitorRegistrationsSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon$1.<init>(VisitorRegistrationsSpec.scala:30)
[error] unit.models.VisitorRegistrationsSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(VisitorRegistrationsSpec.scala:30)
[error] unit.models.VisitorRegistrationsSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(VisitorRegistrationsSpec.scala:30)
```

Comment: As Slick is based on JDBC, the [Acolyte approach](http://acolyte.eu.org/) can be used for unit testing persistence.

Comment: Thanks but this should be relatively easily done per the play docs.  As this is the first of potentially many services that will be built in play we want to do as much as possible the 'play way'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off-hand, it looks as if you have an initialization order problem. Try changing your class-level `val`s to `lazy val` or `def`.

Comment: This did the trick specifically making `val profile = slick.driver.H2Driver` in WithTestDb a lazy val